# Does StreamProvider dispose previous Stream instance and its subscription?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, riverpod

Please look at the following pseudo code using Dart Riverpod.

```
final dependingStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<int>((ref) {
  final depending = ref.watch(dependingProvider);

  if (depending == typeA) {
     return AStream(); // returns stream of int
  } else {
     return BStream(); // returns a different stream of int
  }
});
```

In this case, as `dependingProvider` changes its status, the `StreamProvider` creates another `Stream` instance.

My question is, does the stale `Stream` instance gets disposed of (i.e., its `StreamController` gets `close`d) by Riverpod? Or do we have to handle ourselves somehow?

I saw a similar question here: [Do you have to manually dispose streams from a streamprovider in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777964/do-you-have-to-manually-dispose-streams-from-a-streamprovider-in-flutter) but I wasn't quite sure if the accepted answer refers to my case above.

I understand that `autoDispose` will take care of the disposal when there is nobody listening to the `StreamProvider` itself, but the above case is a different case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and created a sample code.

TL;DR Yes, the `StreamProvider` disposes of the previous `Stream` instance and its subscription.

---

I created the following `Provider`s, so that `streamProvider` switches between `streamA` and `streamB` based on the state of `switcherProvider`.

```
final streamProvider = StreamProvider<int>((ref) {
  final switcher = ref.watch(switcherProvider);

  if (switcher == StreamType.A) {
    return streamA;
  } else {
    return streamB;
  }
});

final streamA = Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (x) {
  print("Emitting $x from stream A");
  return x;
});

final streamB = Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (x) {
  print("Emitting $x from stream B");
  return x;
});

enum StreamType { A, B }

class StreamTypeNotifier extends StateNotifier<StreamType> {
  StreamTypeNotifier() : super(StreamType.A);

  void switchStream() {
    state = state == StreamType.A ? StreamType.B : StreamType.A;
  }
}

final switcherProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<StreamTypeNotifier, StreamType>((ref) {
  return StreamTypeNotifier();
});
```

On tapping FAB, it switches the state of `switcherProvider`.

```
 void _toggleSwitcher() {
    ref.read(switcherProvider.notifier).switchStream();
    ...
 }

...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ref.watch(streamProvider);
    ...
  }
```

The result is this:

[image]

As I tap the FAB for the first time and switch to `streamB`, `streamA` does not emit a new value. As I tap the FAB for the second time and switch to `streamA`, no stream emits any value, since both of the streams are automatically closed.